# SlidingTabLayout bottom padding

Tags: android, pager

I am facing the issue that I have a kind of padding in my SlidingTabLayout.

here is the screenshot
[image]

so as you see, background comes out of the slider on the bottom. Recently, using pagertabstrip library, I nave not see that, but now I tried the new com.example.android.common.view.SlidingTabLayout its definitely there. How to remove this padding?

Thanks

and hiere is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.android.common.view.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/lib_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
         />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/lib_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

style

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_action_bar_color</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="">
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
        <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>

    </style>
```

fragment

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lib_tabs, null);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.lib_pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(this.getFragmentManager()));

        mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lib_tabs);
        mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);

        return view;
    }

    public class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final String[] TITLES = {"Categories", "Home", "Top"};

        public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return TITLES[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TITLES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return LibSimpleInstanceableFragment.newInstance();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

This happens when `distributeEvenly` is `true`. Just comment

```
lp.width = 0;
```

in the `populateTabStrip()` method in the `SlidingTabLayout.java` class and your problem will be solved.

Comment: This should be the approved answer!

Answer (score 1):

Change height to wrap_content:

```
<com.example.android.common.view.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/lib_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
         />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find and open SlidingTabStrip.java (Must be under
   com/example/android/common/view/)
2. Edit the following values as per your needs

   private static final int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS = 0;
   private static final byte DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA = 0x26;
3. You owe me a wine!

Answer (score 0):

Remove minHeight on SlidingTabLayout